# Drywall stored leaning, now bent

Tags: drywall

I've had a contractor doing work at my house for months now. All the while, they had drywall waiting to install, leaning against a wall.

Now the drywall has an obvious bend to it due to being stored in such a way. Should I tell them to get new drywall, or will it mount fully flat?

Comment: Lay it flat for a couple days

Comment: I've seen drywall get a 90 degree bend from being stored leaning in humid conditions. it was otherwise intact.  we didn't try to restore it.

Comment: @Kris +1, should have made it an answer. Just lay it on the floor, it'll flatten out on its own.

Comment: @Kris if you make your comment an answer I'll make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drywall that has warped from leaning against a wall like yours should be laid flat on the floor in stacks that won’t overload the floor joists specifications.

After a couple of days the bend should be gone.

Do not attempt to install without allowing the boards to flatten out because trying to force the curvature out with screws will not work and the screws will be pulled through the drywall attempting to overcome the warpage.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on the bend... too much and it will crack, otherwise it naturally flexes anyway.